# When should I transfer a pothos rooted in water to soil?

Tags: planting, propagation

I recently learned how to take clippings from a pothos plant and root it in water. I am quite new to this sort of gardening and have no idea when I should transfer it to soil. I can see tiny roots growing but I'm not sure how big they should be before I transfer it to soil. When should I plant them? How long should the roots be?

I didn't include a picture originally to try to keep the question general, but as requested here is a picture: [image: A pothos rooted in water]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About half an inch to an inch is sufficient - you don't want them much longer than that because its harder to pot them without damage, and once roots start appearing, its surprising how fast they grow. Try not to damage them when transferring to a soil medium - make a hole large enough to accommodate the rootlets without squashing or bending them, and gently push the soil around them, pressing down lightly at the base of the stem when you're done. Water in well with the pot standing in something to catch the excess - empty that after 30 minutes. Best done into a potting medium that's already damp.

UPDATED ANSWER:

Now you've added pics, wait a bit longer till they're half an inch, although, as its Epipremnum (Pothos) it will be okay to pot it now, but it means you have to pay particular attention to watering - enough to encourage the roots, but not so much that a fungal infection occurs. If you can bear to wait, it shouldn't take long for them to grow.

Comment: Bamboo...what do you think about the use of rooting hormone?  One thing for sure though, please plant in sterilized potting soil, no rock or gravel at the bottom of pot, please use a small pot 2 - 3" diameter.  Allow roots to grow until coming out of the pot before transferring into a slightly bigger pot (4 -6").  Be careful with fertilizer.  Don't apply any for a week or so and then use Osmocote that lasts 4 months or more.  Do not allow bottom of pot to sit in water.  When more established, allow to dry out in between watering.

Comment: you don't need rooting powder with pothos.  They root quite fine without it. For cuttings rooted in water I cut the end of the roots to cause them to divide so you get  more roots.

Comment: @stormy - agree with Kevinsky, though I don't usually cut the roots. Rooted 4 cuttings of this plant myself recently, just in water, potted them up at half inch root (singular) and they're growing fine. Seems to me if a plant can easily root in water, it don't need any extra help!

Comment: @stormy - I should have said they're growing fine in perfectly ordinary multi purpose compost, sitting in a pot on top of a cupboard so it will cascade downwards. After the initial care with watering, I just slosh it some water occasionally now, been there a couple of months, no special care required really once its got going.